# How can I pass params using link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to pass a parameter using link_to. (Also I am trying to use Bootstrap tab)

**ilban.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to '일반공지', '#home', { 'data-toggle' => 'tab', 'aria-controls'=>'home', 'role'=>'tab', :where => 1 } %>
```

**cpu_controller.rb**

```
@where = params[:where]
```

This code doesn't get `where` as an parameter. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

I have not tested it, but it should pass the params that you want.

```
link_to "Search", searches_path(:where => 1, :when => "Today"), { 'data-toggle' => 'tab', 'aria-controls'=>'home', 'role'=>'tab' }
```

**Controller:**

```
@where = params[:where]
```

Comment: I want to use this shape of url: '#home'. It refers to specific id of div and I don't know how to convert this url to searches_path shape..

Comment: @김혜진 so far, if you want to send params to controller u have to call specific route for that. you can see all routes in terminal `rake routes`. Using `#` hash tag and sending to controller its impossible. hash tag is for sending specific content of the page.

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 5, try this syntax for `link_to`

```
link_to 'Show', view_path(:id => view.id), { 'data-toggle' => 'tab', 'aria-controls'=>'home', 'role'=>'tab' }
```

In the place of `view path` you can edit with your `controller path` and pass the valid `id` that you need to link.

Or, try this syntax also to pass params

```
<%= link_to "Add car", {:controller => "car", :action => "add_car", :car   => car.id }%>
```

And add in your controller

> @car = Car.find(params[:car])

Comment: 1. Not `Rails 5` specific syntax. 2.Old ruby syntax in your example, 3.This approach is not suggested in general, because rails you can change model `to_param` method and have something else as a member path identification(like name or random number). harcoding that to be `id` will make it harder to change it. Instead pass full object like `view_path(view)` instead of `view_path(:id => view.id)`

Comment: I want to use this shape of url: '#home'. It refers to specific id of div and I don't know how to convert this url to searches_path shape..